# What is the difference between Informix server and Informix SE?

Tags: upgrade, informix

My question is:

I have informix SE  7.2 with old database. I write my programs in Java and sometimes I have problems with old version. Can I do some thing to upgrade my server to new version of Informix online ex. 14.10?  What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a big, broad question.

Informix SE (Standard Engine) is a relatively simple and very ancient SQL server that uses Informix C-ISAM as the storage manager.  It is very simple to install; there is no configuration worth mentioning; it runs, and it keeps running, and it works.

Informix (Informix Dynamic Server or IDS, but it has had many names, and is currently officially known as just "Informix") is a relatively modern SQL server that uses wholly different storage management technology.  It takes more effort to set it up and configure it and keep it running.  However, once it is running, it runs well and keeps running.

To upgrade from SE 7.2 to Informix 14.10, you would have to install the new software (in a new directory, separate from the one where Informix SE is installed) and get an Informix server running.  You would have to run DB-Export on each of your Informix SE databases, and then use DB-Import to import them to IDS.  You'd need to review your code to ensure that it uses transactions sensibly.  You'd probably want to use a logged database in IDS, not an unlogged database, but that means you need to be cognizant of transactions.  However, the vast bulk of your code would not change — the connection string would need to connect to the IDS database (server) instead of SE.

There's a lot more details to the whole subject than the quick summary above.  However, you'd need to ask fairly focussed, detailed questions for it to be suitable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: you win with the "that's a big broad question".